# IIS URL Rewrite - IIS 7

Tags: url, iis, url-rewriting

I am new to using IIS Url Rewrite. I installed it and set up a rule using IIS, but nothing happens when I try to access a url in my localhost. Below is what IIS put in my web.config. When I access this url mysite/srcc_development_2012/login/default.aspx, based on the rule I set up it should redirect to google, but it does not work. What am I missing?

```
    <rewrite>
        <rules>
            <rule name="SRCC" patternSyntax="Wildcard" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="mysite/srcc_development_2012/*" />
                <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.google.com" />
                <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
                </conditions>
            </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
```

Answer (score 2):

i know this is an older thread but it is unanswered and shows up in the search..

here is how i would do this:

```
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="SRCC" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="(.*)" ignoreCase="true" />
      <conditions>
        <add input="{URL}" pattern="^srcc_development_2012(.*)?" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.google.com" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

The value in  is what comes after the domain (stackoverflow.com/THIS/IS/THE-URL, where stackoverflow.com is the {HTTP_HOST} (but we arent using that for this rule)).

Answer (score 0):

**The below one should work :**

But make sure you add this rule to the login folder.

```
<rule name="redirect" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url=".*" />
      <action type="Redirect" url="https://google.com" />
</rule>
```